# Nutch error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mongodb, nutch

I'm trying to run **Apache Nutch** from **Eclipse**. I followed the instructions at http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/RunNutchInEclipse. However, sources of "parse-html" (both java and test) has errors. I run it anyway, it reads and fetches URL's from the **seed.txt** and returns this error:

```
Fetcher: finished at 2012-03-31 17:21:56, elapsed: 00:00:07
ParseSegment: starting at 2012-03-31 17:21:56
ParseSegment: segment: crawl/segments/20120331172142
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
```

I would like to point out that my goal is to get indexes from **Nutch** and store them in **MongoDB**.

Comment: i am not sure if the nutch documentation is up to date. better u turn to linux (or VM) and settle it out. Even if u somehoe manage to solve this issue, u will get more such ahead if u stick with windows

Comment: I already work in Ubuntu. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 3 jars and added them to the project as external jars and it worked. Those jars are : **cyberneko.jar**, **rome-0.9.jar** and **tagsoup-1.2.jar** and you can find all by a simple google search.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to `ivy.xml`:

```
<dependency org="rome" name="rome" rev="0.9" />
<dependency org="net.sourceforge.nekohtml" name="nekohtml" rev="1.9.13" />
<dependency org="org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup" name="tagsoup" rev="1.2.1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Here are two ways that might help:

- Modify conf/log4j.properties file to report DEBUG messages;
- read the hadoop.log file which is usually located in $NUTCH_HOME or $NUTCH_HOME/logs.

By examining these messages, you should be able to spot the problem.

Here is a tutorial on Running Nutch in Eclipse which also talks about several error handling.